# How can I use Django ORM outside without problems?

Tags: python, mysql, django, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I use Django ORM for telegram bot which written with PyTelegramBotAPI lib and I had a trouble `MySQL Server has gone away`, then I increased `MAX_CONNECTION` and `wait_timeout`, but it didn't help, now I haven't errors but the bot falls every few hours.

Comment: How exactly do you connect to the MySQL server?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Django queries

Comment: What do you mean by using it "outside"?

Comment: @VokaPytyuk: what I mean is, how did you configure the connection.

Comment: Your `settings.py` file has a key called `DATABASES` where you configure your database connections and credentials

Comment: ORM just translate your Python code into raw SQL, it does not have any other impact on the database. You have database settings set in your settings.py file, as @rtindru said. I also assume that you can make some on-time "database configuration" via 3 part libraries, but not with ORM.

Comment: @rtindru I mean out of typical django project, I wrote telegram bot code as custom django command

Comment: @Chiefir yes, I configured `DATABASE` in `settings.py`

Comment: You can use Django ORM only with Django framework

Comment: If you need an ORM that works with multiple Python web frameworks; check out SQL Alchemy. I've heard that with the right connective tissue, it can work with Flask, Django, Pyramid, e.t.c

Comment: @rtindru it's good, but i used django because it provides useful web admin